# Is it possible to get a random tweet of a timeline with JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jsonp

I'm looking into the Twitter JSONP api and I was wondering if it is possible to get a "random" tweet out of the *entire* timeline. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

Twitter IDs use [Snowflake](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html) - a roughly ordered 64 bit number.  So, you could generate a random 64 bit number and **hope** that it's the ID of a valid tweet, it's not very reliable.

You could use the [Public Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline) to get the 20 most recent tweets.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Pulling the latest *n* tweets and generating a random number between 1 and *n* would be the only chance to get a "random" tweet. The max number of tweets is 200 in one page. Hm... maybe I can get random page *x* with size 1.